# What does B stand for in MB/GB, bit or byte?

Tags: byte, bit

In PC properties (i.e. My Computer -> Properties), what does B stand for in MB or GB. Does it define bit or byte?

Comment: what this question makes sense here ?

Comment: check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte

Comment: Better yet, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte which provides the rationale for the choices of `B` and `b` by the SI and/or IEEE committees, despite the possible conflict with the bel unit.  `PLEASE` do make a minimal attempt at answering the question before posting on SO...

Comment: Question is closed, but the better answer is, "B should be byte.  b should be bit.  Similarly, M should be 1024, while m is 1000."  "should" referring to the most common usage that is most meaningful.  However, there are plenty of exceptions where some people will just capitalize or lowercase based on their desires, MBPS (Megabytes Per Second) or mbps (megabits per second), with the p sometimes replaced with a slash.  So, while it is best to treat B as byte and b as bit, and M as binary/base-2 and m as SI/base-10, when reading it's safest to just consider this ambiguously uncertain.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Byte. bit is lowercase. MB = Megabyte, Mb is megabit.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that it's meaning was case sensitive.

Comment: @user The same goes for M (mega) and m (milli)

Answer (score 8):

Byte for B,
bit for b.

This is international standard.

Answer (score 4):

Upper case B always means Byte, and lower case means bit.

For example when you see internet speeds listed in MB/s, that refers to MegaBytes per second, and when you see it listed as Mb/s that refers to Megabits per second.

Comment: You are fully correct, however, people are lazily mixing B and b, so it's hard for me (who knows the difference) to know what it actally means when developers uses these letters interchangably. =(

Answer (score 1):

The letter "B" stands for "byte".